# Pandas Styler conditional formatting based on comparison of each row with last row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a large dataframe that comes from calculation with varying number of columns and rows:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  5  1  5  1  4
1  0  3  1  1  5
2  2  5  2  5  1
3  2  3  2  3  4
```

Each column has last row that decides coloring of each cell in that column. Each cell of the column needs to be compared with the last cell of that particular column and then the condition to be applied is: `if s>s[-1]: background-color: green, if s<s[-1]: background-color: red, if s==s[-1]: background-color: yellow.`

To get output like this:
[image]

Therefore I need to highlight all rows except last using the above conditions.

I tried  with two conditions but could not get the third condition:

```py
data = [[5,1,5,1,4], [0,3,1,1,5], [2,5,2,5,1],[2,3,2,3,4]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
       
def highlight_greater(s):
    is_max = s > s[-1]
    return ['background-color: green' if i else 'background-color: yellow'  for i in is_max ]   
    
df.style.apply(highlight_greater)
```

I don't know how to use three condition using this function. Can some one help?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
colors = {1: 'green', 0: 'yellow', -1: 'red'}

# mask to leave the last row without style
mask = np.tile(df.index==df.index[-1], (df.shape[1],1)).T

# compute the sign of difference to last row
# and map colors + style
style = (np.sign(df.sub(df.iloc[-1])
                   .mask(mask)
                 )
           .replace(colors)
           .radd('background-color: ')
         )

# apply style
df.style.apply(lambda x: style, axis=None)
```

Output:

[image: pandas style difference row]

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 0, 2, 2],
                   'b': [1, 3, 5, 3],
                   'c': [5, 1, 2, 2],
                   'd': [1, 1, 5, 3],
                   'e': [4, 5, 1, 4]})
```

Comment: when I ran this i got: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Comment: Are you sure you ran my exact code? I don't use `rstrip`. Check the full error message. And make sure to run my exact code on the provided example (see Reddit for a reproducible input).

Comment: Yes, this the full code i used: `data = [[5,1,5,1,4], [0,3,1,1,5], [2,5,2,5,1],[2,3,2,3,4]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
       
colors = {1: 'green', 0: 'yellow', -1: 'red'}

mask = np.tile(df.index==df.index[-1], (df.shape[1],1)).T

style = (np.sign(df.sub(df.iloc[-1])
                   .mask(mask)
                 )
           .replace(colors)
           .radd('background-color: ')
         )

df.style.apply(lambda x: style, axis=None)`

Comment: I checked again and it works without issue. Please ensure you have an up to date pandas (tested on 1.4.3).

Comment: @Shiva have you tested again? What is your pandas version? I'm wondering whether the error comes from the masked values. Try without the `.mask(mask)`, if this works without error (this will also color the last list in yellow), then you can `mask` with a white color.

Comment: So was the issue due to the mask? It would be great to provide details on what triggered the error for future readers ;)